# MongoDB Java driver 3.0 error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I use java driver 3.0 using gradle, I got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/bson/io/InputBuffer
at org.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.create(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:42)
```

Any help?

Comment: maybe a duplicate (or missing) jar. Can you list what jars you end up with?

Comment: bson-3.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar is used

Comment: and no other jar files *at all*? How about the mongoDB driver jar file?

Comment: mongodb-driver-3.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: maybe try a non-SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: I use the builg.gradle file in http://blog.mongodb.org/post/59769560940/the-mongodb-java-driver-3-0-whats-changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use github source and make it. Everything is well now. I think that the snapshot version has some problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem several days ago, here is the solution:

Change to `mongo-java-driver-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, not `mongodb-driver-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Seems like mongo java driver changed it's artifactiId (for maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using gradle, here is the correct java library for mongo 3.0

```
'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.0-rc1'
```